# Software-center crashes: bug or configuration error?

Tags: 13.04, software-center

For several weeks, I've been having trouble with software-center under Ubuntu 13.04. It crashes silently, just a few seconds after execution. After each crash, syslog records a cryptic error:

```
Oct  3 23:14:11 mattbuntu kernel: [24085.941708] traps: software-center[20640] trap int3 ip:7f9ac3880135 sp:7fffaf98bf60 error:0
```

Software-center emits the following error when executed from the terminal:

```
[matt@mattbuntu:~]$software-center

** (software-center:4114): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-QORifKNTUU: Connection refused
2013-10-04 18:18:21,219 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
2013-10-04 18:18:21,991 - softwarecenter.plugin - INFO - activating plugin '<module 'webapps_activation' from '/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/plugins/webapps_activation.pyc'>'
2013-10-04 18:18:22,001 - softwarecenter.fixme - WARNING - logs to the root logger: '('/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/importer.py', 51, 'find_module')'
2013-10-04 18:18:22,000 - root - ERROR - Could not find any typelib for LaunchpadIntegration
2013-10-04 18:18:22,062 - softwarecenter.db.pkginfo_impl.aptcache - INFO - aptcache.open()
2013-10-04 18:18:25,068 - softwarecenter.fixme - WARNING - logs to the root logger: '('/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/utils.py', 271, 'get_title_from_html')'
2013-10-04 18:18:25,068 - root - WARNING - failed to parse: '<div style="background-color: #161513; width:1680px; height:200px;">
 <div style="background: url('/site_media/exhibits/2013/09/AAMFP_Leaderboard_700x200_1.jpg') top left no-repeat; width:700px; height:200px;"></div>
</div>' ('ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 70: ordinal not in range(128))
2013-10-04 18:18:25,069 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.views.lobbyview - WARNING - skipping exhibit for: 'u'amnesia-amfp'' not available
2013-10-04 18:18:25,070 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.views.lobbyview - WARNING - skipping exhibit for: 'u'wakfu'' not available

(software-center:4114): Gdk-ERROR **: The program 'software-center' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter)'.
  (Details: serial 2575 error_code 9 request_code 62 minor_code 0)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the GDK_SYNCHRONIZE environment
   variable to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

I have tried reinstalling the package, but that did not work. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does the Software Updater crash as well? Did you upgrade to 13.04, or was it a clean install? Also, could you run `software-center` from Terminal and give us the full error? This well help us diagnose your problem.

Comment: Hi Dillmo. It was a clean install. Software updater works great. The full error is here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6194248/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is an error in software-center. The [bug report is here.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/1163886)

To fix the issue, you must patch the bug yourself:

- open `/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/lobbyview.py`
- add a `#` before the line `self.exhibit_banner.set_exhibits([FeaturedExhibit()])`
- restart software-center

Comment: This solution worked perfectly for me. For context, I was messing with themes and Gnome Shell skins before encountering this error. I'm posting this comment in hopes that anyone else with issues after theme changes will see this indexed on Google.