# Software Center GUI consume too much memory. Is this a known bug or so-designed?

Tags: software-center

When I tried to open Software Center (GUI version) from left panel, it soon consumes more than 7GB memory. After staying at 7GB for a while, it quits with nothing coming out, as shown in this picture: http://tinypic.com/r/im3xc6/8. But when I run Software Center from command line by typing software-center, it comes out smoothly, using only a small amount of memory. What is more strange, I can run GUI Software Center from left panel correctly before today; this problem only happens since today. So I want to know, if the GUI Software Center is known buggy, or it is purposely design not to work?  Thanks for your answer.

A follow-up: This problem is automatically resolved after uninstalling the xldm display manager and login into default lightdm. Software Center GUI now runs as expected, fast and reliable. xldm is really a disaster.

Comment: You can look at this question for alternatives:[Are there alternatives to software center?](http://askubuntu.com/q/339697/36315)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the spike in CPU usage when I opened the Software Center (searching from Dash) GUI. The tallest spike is from the moment I clicked on it to open it, then it becomes normal.

I also checked via System Monitor (after seeing your image). It works according to spikes: gets around 300+ MiB in first then goes to 200-ish MiB (near to `compiz`, much less than Firefox).

I don't know what you're talking about, it cannot be using 7GB normally. Contact developers or submit a bug report.

For your other part, "it quits with nothing coming out," you might be facing a separate bug. Please see this question for a solution: [Software-center crashes: bug or configuration error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/353449/software-center-crashes-bug-or-configuration-error?rq=1)

I can assure you that Software Center GUI isn't designed to not work or quit itself on purpose.

---

[image: CPU usage when opening Software Center GUI]

Comment: By "Dash" do you mean the top bar in the desktop? If it is, my Dash contains no icons, not to mention CPU usage. I post this issue in the question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/563130/how-to-restore-icons-on-the-top-right-corner-in-the-top-bar, but no one has answered it yet.

Comment: The Dash is primarily a search-based utility. You can search for an application that you want to open. You can also use the mouse only, through the Filer option. Basically, opening an app from the Launcher (a locked application on the left sidebar) or from Dash search are the same thing. As for the topbar's CPU graph, that's an app I've installed for monitoring real-time CPU usage.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you report it to developers. Meanwhile if you you want an alternative, Deepin Software Centre is nice. Here's how to install it:

http://www.noobslab.com/2014/05/deepin-software-center-v32v3021.html

I also keep Synaptic nearby.

How to install:

Open terminal.

Type: "sudo apt-get install synaptic" without quotes.

Press enter, put in your root password.

Comment: Thanks. Synaptic works fine, but it has a deficiency: people can not review a software, like Software Center does.

Comment: Deepin SC should be fine then.