# Software-Center crashing bug (Bus error)

Tags: 14.04, software-center

My Ubuntu Software Center keeps crashing when I try to run it. What's even weirder is that this is happening on two laptops and across two versions of Ubuntu (14.04 and 16.10). On 14.04 this is the error that comes up:

```
...$ software-center

2016-12-07 20:03:48,104 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
2016-12-07 20:03:48,496 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - WARNING - Could not get usefulness from server, no username in config file
2016-12-07 20:03:48,498 - softwarecenter.plugin - INFO - activating plugin '<module 'webapps_activation' from '/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/plugins/webapps_activation.pyc'>'
2016-12-07 20:03:48,537 - softwarecenter.db.pkginfo_impl.aptcache - INFO - aptcache.open()
2016-12-07 20:03:48,780 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - WARNING - error creating bsddb: '(22, 'Invalid argument -- BDB0054 illegal flag combination specified to DB_ENV->open')' (corrupted?)
2016-12-07 20:03:48,781 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - ERROR - trying to repair DB failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/backend/reviews/__init__.py", line 358, in _save_review_stats_cache_blocking
    self._dump_bsddbm_for_unity(outfile, outdir)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/backend/reviews/__init__.py", line 377, in _dump_bsddbm_for_unity
    0600)
DBInvalidArgError: (22, 'Invalid argument -- BDB0054 illegal flag combination specified to DB_ENV->open')
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/overrides/GLib.py:535: Warning: Source ID 74 was not found when attempting to remove it
  return super(MainContext, self).iteration(may_block)
Bus error (core dumped)
```

I tried various things to fix it (including [How can I fix my software center?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/687847/how-can-i-fix-my-software-center) and [Software-center crashes: bug or configuration error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/353449)), and even more on my 16.10 machine and in the end I don't recall anything ever working properly. Besides, both times it was happening on fresh installs of ubuntu. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: was there any significant thing done before this started happening ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Software-center crashes: bug or configuration error?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/353449/software-center-crashes-bug-or-configuration-error)

Comment: I tried doing what the top answer suggest and it changed nothing. I don't think it's the same problem. Also, I didn't do anything at all to ubuntu or to the software center before this, the computer and installation is brand new.

Comment: If I could ask one more thing, is the last line about it being a `Bus error` significant in any way? Because my firefox is also crashing and the last line is the same.

Comment: That's  a hardware (BUS) issue. is your computer new?

Comment: Yes, completely brand new. It's a Spectre x360 13t if that helps. What would the bus be referring to then? And why would it only happen for two programs?

Comment: I upgraded to kernel 4.8.14 and while it could have been something else, the issue seems to have been resolved.

Comment: Glad to hear you have fixed it, guess that was the solution!